# warning C4133, incompatible types

Tags: c

Visual Studio show me warnings like:
warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'char *'
warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'char *' to 'FILE *'

The warnings are on lines where is comment "this line". How can I fix it?

My code:

```
typedef struct {
int numberOfCity;
tListOfCity* list;
double** distances;
} tDatabase;

tDatabase* LoadDatabase(char* file) {
FILE* file;
tDatabase *input;
char data[100];
int i, j, number = 0;

input = (tDatabase*) calloc(1, sizeof (tDatabase));
input->list = NULL;

file = fopen("file.txt", "r");   //this line
fscanf(file, "%d", &number);     //this line
input->numberOfCity = number;

input->distances = (double**) calloc(data->numberOfCity, sizeof (double*));
for (i = 0; i < input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    input->distances[i] = (double*) calloc(input->numberOfCity, sizeof (double));
}

for (i = 0; i <= input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    fgets(data, sizeof (data), file);    //this line
    input->list = AddOnEnd(input->list, CreateCity(data));
}

for (i = 0; i < input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < input->numberOfCity; j++) {
        fscanf(file, "%f", &input->distances[i][j]);   //this line
    }

fclose(file);
return input;
```

}

Comment: The code is ill-formed; your function has both a parameter and a local variable named "`file`."  What version of the compiler is this?  Visual C++ 2010, 2012, and 2013 all reject this code as ill-formed with "error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'file'."

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I agree, it shouldn't compile in the first place.

Comment: Visual C++ 2008

I get some other errors.

Answer (score 5):

There are two `file` variables in your code.
First is what you pass in as parameter, and the other is declared as `FILE * file`. Change the parameter to `fileName` or something similar and patch the code to reflect that.

```
tDatabase* LoadDatabase(char* fileName) {
FILE* file;
tDatabase *input;
char data[100];
int i, j, number = 0;

input = (tDatabase*) calloc(1, sizeof (tDatabase));
input->list = NULL;

file = fopen("file.txt", "r");   //this line
fscanf(file, "%d", &number);     //this line
input->numberOfCity = number;

input->distances = (double**) calloc(data->numberOfCity, sizeof (double*));
for (i = 0; i < input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    input->distances[i] = (double*) calloc(input->numberOfCity, sizeof (double));
}

for (i = 0; i <= input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    fgets(data, sizeof (data), file);    //this line
    input->list = AddOnEnd(input->list, CreateCity(data));
}

for (i = 0; i < input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < input->numberOfCity; j++) {
        fscanf(file, "%f", &input->distances[i][j]);   //this line
    }

fclose(file);
return input;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't give the same name to an argument and a local variable:

```
tDatabase* LoadDatabase(char* file) {
FILE* file;
```

And probably it's a good opportunity to make your function to respect the filename it gets as an argument (now it always opens "file.txt").